# Marker does not work on 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Is anyone using Marker (https://www.insynchq.com/) app on Ubuntu?

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04, and Marker does not work now. Actually, nothing happens when I start it. I don't even get an error by starting it via console `marker start`.

However, it does not appear in the top bar nor I can activate it with any of shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note this bug report on the insync forums which pertains to your case:

- [Insync stopped working on Ubuntu Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS](https://forums.insynchq.com/t/insync-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-xenial-xerus-16-04-lts/5481)

And I can certainly duplicate your experience on my Xenial setup. Current best advice as per this bug report is:

1. Wait for a Xenial package
2. Use the commandline version, which seems to be working despite the shortcomings of the gui:

   ```
   andrew@athens:~$ insync-headless --help
   insync - command line interface for the Insync process

   available commands

   accept_all_new_shares
   accept_share
   add_account
   force_sync
   get_account_information
   get_actions_required
   get_domain_link
   get_errors
   get_file_status
   get_new_shares
   get_private_link
   get_proxy
   get_public_link
   get_recent_changes
   get_root_drive_files
   get_status
   get_sync_progress
   manage_ignore_list
   manage_selective_sync
   move_folder
   open_in_gdrive
   pause_syncing
   quit
   reject_all_new_shares
   reject_share
   remove_account
   remove_from_insync
   resume_syncing
   retry_errors
   set_autostart
   set_export_option
   set_proxy
   set_selective_sync
   share
   start

   Run insync help <command> for help with a specific command
   ```

Comment: Any idea how to take a piece of the screen? which command to use? `start`  does nothing